# Strange behavior of scrollHeight in firefox on div with padding and overflow:auto

Tags: html, firefox, scrollbar, padding

Here it is, http://jsfiddle.net/YNKws/

```
<div id="div1" style="padding: 2px; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="height:30px;">lalala</div>
  <div style="height:30px;">lalala</div>
</div>

var d = $("#div1");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(d.height(),d[0].scrollHeight);
  d.height(d.height() - 1);
}
```

There's div with padding and overflow:auto. And in firefox there's strange behavior of div's scrollHeight value. When we set up the div's height smaller than it's original height, that's natural to expect that the scrollbar appears immediately and the scrollHeight value remains the same. Chrome suits theese expecatations but not firefox, the last one doesn't draw scrollbar, decreases bottom padding and scrollHeight when the deviation of the original height is smaller than div's padding.

Is it a bug and is there a fix of this 'bug'?

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox behavior is the one the CSS spec requires: padding on the thing with overflow doesn't cause overflow on its own.

Comment: is there any documented article about this behaviour? my scrollHeight is not consistent after changing height of element with overflow-y:auto